# First site page display to Second site

Tags: html, web-hosting

Good day,
I'm planning to create a site that can create pages and that pages can display to another site, is that possible?

The idea is to

1. Create pages on site A
2. Display pages on site B

Thank you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<iframe>` to display HTML from another source

```html
<iframe src="B.html"></iframe>
```

You can also use URL

```html
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```